# Divide multiple values contained in a single string in php

Tags: php, explode, divide

Hi,

I have a string like this:

```
$coord = "1,0 1,8 7,13 7,94";
```

and I need to divide by 100 each one of the values to get something like this:

```
0.01,0 0.01,0.08 0.07,0.13 0.07,0.94
```

So I tried this:

```
$pair=explode(" ", $coord);

foreach ($pair as $val) {
    $sing = explode(",", $val);
    foreach ($sing as $div) {
     $res = ($div/100);
    }
    $sing_d = implode(",", $res);
}

$result = implode(" ", $sing_d);

print ($result);
```

but I get an error:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: `$res` is not an array, implode needs an array to be parsed

Comment: Why is $res not an array? Its inside a foreach.

Comment: It would have been if  you had put `$res[] = $div/100`. Note the square brackets. Also the (round) parentheses you put are not needed, nor do they make the result an array.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to find and replace all numbers by their value divided by 100:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/\d+(\.\d+)?/", function ($match) {
    return $match[0]/100;
}, $coord);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I didnt know that function. Its great. Thank you.